# how to fetch items if any search keyword matched?

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch

I have this document in my elastic DB.I am using this package
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@elastic/elasticsearch

I am searching on `title`.

I am doing like this.

```
const result= await client.search({
      index: 'products',
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "wildcard": { "title": "*" + search + "*" }
            }
          ],
          "minimum_should_match": 1
        }
      }
```

when I search "title"  this `issue` . it give me **one result** but When I am seacrhing `i have issue` . it is giving zero or `0` result.why ? is it possible to fetch that data.`issue` keyword is present in first collection why it is not picking ?

```
[
  {
    "_index": "products",
    "_id": "wZRh3n8Bs9qQzO6fvTTS",
    "_score": 1.0,
    "_source": {
      "title": "laptop issues",
      "description": "laptop have issue present in according"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "products",
    "_id": "wpRh3n8Bs9qQzO6fvzQM",
    "_score": 1.0,
    "_source": {
      "title": "buy mobile",
      "description": "mobile is in Rs 250"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "products",
    "_id": "w5Rh3n8Bs9qQzO6fvzTz",
    "_score": 1.0,
    "_source": {
      "title": "laptop payment",
      "description": "laptop payment is given in any way"
    }
  }
]
```

how to search on keywords? any keyword match . I need to pick that whole colloection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to match only some of the word from query then you can use `match query` with `operator` set to `or`.

```json
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "title": {
        "query": "i have issues",
        "operator": "or"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Update**

To run the query which you mentioned in comment, You can use [match_bool_prefix](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-bool-prefix-query.html) query.

```json
{
  "query": {
    "match_bool_prefix": {
      "title": {
        "query": "i have issu"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thank almost correct.. but one point is missing I said if i search `i have issu` still I want to search element.. here is it giving me zero or 0 output

Comment: updated my answer. please check.